# Palindrome Function

Tags: c++, palindrome

I need to rewrite the program to use a function isPalindrome.  It needs to input a 5 digit integer and return a boolean (true if it is a palindrome, false if it is not), and it cannot contain any cout statements.  I am not sure how I would do this without a cout function. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number, digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5;

    cout << "\nEnter a 5-digit integer: ";
    cin >> number;

//Break down input number into individual digits:
    digit1 = number / 10000;
    digit2 = number % 10000 / 1000;
    digit3 = number % 10000 / 100;
    digit4 = number % 10000 / 10;
    digit5 = number % 10;

    if ( digit1 == digit5 && digit2 == digit4 )
        cout << number <<" is a palindrome.\n";
             else
             cout << number << " is not a palindrome.\n";
             return 0;
         }
int isPalindrome ()
{

}
```

Comment: Hint: `isPalindrome` should have a `bool` return type according to your requirement. You need to `return` statement in place of `cout` in the function.

Comment: `isPalindrome` also needs input parameters - you have to pass data into it.

Comment: I am lost on how to rewrite it though, do i keep the main function as is and just have the boolean in ispalindrome?

Comment: Do you know how you would use the function?  (Not what it does, just where and how you'd use it)

Comment: Hint: there's no reason to read the number as a number if you're going to treat it like a string.

Comment: I was thinking of calling the isPalindrome function in the main function. not sure if that would work.

Comment: @user2085224, You move the code that manipulates the number to find out if it's a palindrome to the function. You should be able to call it like `isPalindrome(12321)` and expect a true or false return value. The point of the function is to make that whole series of operations to find out whether it's a palindrome a single, easy call.

Comment: Putting aside the inefficient and static way of figuring out the digits, you're code is basically correct already. Just copy all the code under your first comment into a function `bool isPalindrome(int number)`, replace `cout << number <<" is a palindrome.\n";` with `return true;` and `cout << number << " is not a palindrome.\n";` with `return false;`, and you're done!

Answer (score 5):

This should help get you started (without ruining too much of the fun)

```
int main(){
    //accept integer input using cin
    if(isPalindrome(input))
       cout << "yaay!";
    else
       cout << "nooouuu!";

}

bool isPalindrome (int input)
{
   //test things here
   return ( digit1 == digit5 && digit2 == digit4 ) 
   // ^ returns true if condition satisfied
}
```

---

Additionally, your way of separating out the digits is incorrect. It should be:

```
digit1 = number/10000 % 10;
digit2 = number/1000 % 10;
digit3 = number/100 % 10;
digit4 = number/10 % 10;
digit5 = number % 10;
```

Ofcourse, the above should actually be in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have to be specified how many digits does the number contain. You can try something like this:

```
    bool isPalindrome(int number) {
        int reverse = 0, copy = number;
        while(copy != 0) {
            reverse = reverse*10 + copy%10;
            copy /= 10;
        }
        return number == reverse;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string s;
    cout<<"\nEnter a string : " ;
    cin>>s;
    int length = s.length();

    char* arr = new char();

    int k = length;

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= length ; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = s[k];
        k -= 1;
    }

    if(!palindrome(s, arr, length))
    {
        cout<<"\nNot Palindrome\n";
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"\nPalindrome\n";
    }
}

bool palindrome(string& s, char* arr, int length)
{
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]!= s[j])
        {
            return false;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return true;
}
```